# ASP.NET MVC Model Binder Fails with Strings that look like version numbers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-4

This should be straight-forward, but here goes - we're using MVC4 to handle a multi-part Form request to upload a binary along with some meta-data via a strongly-typed view in MVC4.

One of the fields is a version number for the file (i.e. something like **0.0.6**, **0.4.5-pre**, etc...)

I'm getting the following error from the model binder when it tries to bind this version number field to the model field (string type):

> {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type
>   'Models.NewFileVersion' failed because no type converter can convert
>   between these types."}

Specifically the error can be traced to our "VersionNumber" field - any ideas as to why this might be happening?

**Edit:** Source code below

NewFileVersion.cs

```
public class NewFileVersion
{
    [Display(Name = "Version # (0.67, 0.66-pre, etc...)")]
    [Required]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "ChangeLog must be between 30 an 2000 characters", MinimumLength = 30)]
    [Display(Name = "Version Notes (will be visible to end-users)")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ChangeLog { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Target Platform")]
    [UIHint("Enum")]
    public FileType PlatformTarget { get; set; }
}
```

New.cshtml

```
    @model ViewModels.NewFileVersion
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}
<div class="container" id="main-content">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>
            New</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>NewFileVersion</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Version)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Version)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Version)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChangeLog)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChangeLog)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChangeLog)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlatformTarget)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PlatformTarget)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="">
                        File:</label></div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input type="file" name="fileData" required="required" /></div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FilesController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NewFileVersion version, HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        //if our model is valid
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //etc....             
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid file submission");

        return View("New", version);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post ur model class & controller action implementation? There is no code here and that would be hard for people to figure out.

Comment: From the error it doesn't look like one of the fields is actually a string.  It's trying to convert something to type Models.NewFileVersion.  Is this an enum type?  But as @tugberk says if you could post the code listing that would help.

Comment: @tugberk done and done - added the source code. There IS an enum field in-play here (and i have a custom editor template for it) but that's not where the model binding is throwing an error. It's failing on the "version" field towards the top of the page.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb: can you try renaming the `version` parameter for your `create` action (e.g: `public ActionResult Create(NewFileVersion fileVersion, HttpPostedFileBase fileData) { ... }`)? The model binder may be getting confused between the `string version` model property and the `NewFileVersion version` action parameter.

Comment: @pjumble - that worked! add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Please don't put MVC 4 in the title unless the problem ONLY occurs with MVC 4.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com, actually, that's not how tags work here. The OP using MVC 4 warrants putting it among the tags. SO is not your JIRA. :)

Comment: @ bzlm that's not how tags work here - tags != titles. MVC 4 is beta, so you rule out many folks not using Beta and you attract the attention of folks looking for beta bugs. Why limit yourself to a small subset of ASP.NET MVC users (4 beta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the `version` parameter for your `Create` action, e.g:

```
public ActionResult Create(NewFileVersion fileVersion, HttpPostedFileBase fileData) { ... }
```

The model binder may be getting confused between the `string version` model property and the `NewFileVersion version` action parameter.

---

You can see why this happens in the [`BindModel`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/150e8b96e806#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fDefaultModelBinder.cs) method, because the model has a property exactly matching the name of the action parameter it tries to bind as a simple type/model rather than a complex one.